# If you delete your Nintendo Network ID, what happens to the Pokemon Transferred using Pokemon Bank and Pokemon Transfer?

Tags: pokemon-bank, nintendo-network-id

I just need help about the Nintendo Network ID, my Pokemon Bank Trial has just expired and I can't transfer my Pokemon to Pokemon Y without Pokemon Bank and Transfer. That's fine, because I already finished transferring my Pokemon to Y from older games. However, I started thinking about deleting my Nintendo Network ID, and since Pokemon Bank is something you bought from the E-shop, I just thought maybe my Pokemon that were transferred may be deleted, or returned to the other game along with my Nintendo ID. Can someone tell me if it what will happen to the transferred Pokemon?

Comment: There is no reason why you will lose your transferred Pokemon, and even less likely that they will return to your previous game. On top of that, you already paid for the service of PokeBank and it doesn't make sense that a service would be reversed if you stopped doing so (even if it was the free trial period). The only way you can lose your transferred Pokemon (well, all your game progress actually) would be if you lose your save file (through a reset for example).

Answer (score 3):

This was a while ago, so you might've already done stuff? but those pokemon are probably going to be deleted.

Strictly speaking, the [NNI](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Nintendo-Network-ID/FAQ/Nintendo-3DS/Nintendo-3DS-841666.html) isn't the kind of thing you putz around with. It's a dangerous thing to delete out of nowhere.

**Why?** Because the NNI is connected to the currency in your account. It is what allows you to buy things. And the money doesn't transfer between regions (you can't change dollars to yen) so you'd lose that.

In that link before, there was something said that could be considered pretty scary. Basically (emphasis mine):

> Can I register the same Nintendo Network ID on more than one Nintendo 3DS system?
>
> No, this is not possible. **Your Nintendo Network ID is tied to your software and/or additional content you have purchased and downloaded.** As the rights of usage for software you have purchased apply only to a single Nintendo 3DS family system, you can only register your Nintendo Network ID on one system.

The bolded statement makes people think they cannot ever change their NNI. But that's [not the case](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2220/%7E/what-happens-to-my-nintendo-eshop-purchases-when-i-link-a-nintendo-network-id?) because you can add a new NNI:

> What is retained:
>
> All game licenses purchased prior to linking a Nintendo Network ID.
>
> Funds added prior to linking a Nintendo Network ID. (See "What is NOT retained" for restrictions.)
>
> Additionally, if a Nintendo Network ID is linked to both a Wii U and a Nintendo 3DS, the Nintendo eShop balance is consolidated and shared between them.
>
> All free software demos downloaded prior to linking a Nintendo Network ID.

As far as [deleting](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2224/%7E/how-to-delete-a-nintendo-network-id) goes, though... completely different story. you can keep your stuff if you [format your system memory](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/258). That's because:

> Deleting a Nintendo Network ID will also delete the following information associated to the account: Nintendo eShop activity and balance, Friend List, Miiverse activity, and registered e-mail address.

Now! I know what you're thinking: These are prior purchases, they don't have anything to do with my NNI, blah blah blah," but, here's the thing-- deleting your NNI has a process to it, and THIS is a part of the process:

> Agree to the following points:
>
> **The Nintendo eShop and all associated purchases will be deleted, and cannot be downloaded. This applies to purchases made with this Nintendo Network ID both on the Wii U and Nintendo 3DS.**
>
> Any remaining balance in the Nintendo eShop account will be deleted and cannot be recovered or refunded. This applies to funds added to this Nintendo Network ID both on the Wii U and Nintendo 3DS.
>
> The Friends List associated to this Nintendo Network ID will be deleted.
>
> Any posts and comments made on Miiverse will be deleted.

Long story short: If you do it, do it carefully.